Can I make a router "transparently" pass a subnet?
Sorry if the title is misleading, not sure how else to describe it.  Given the following (simplified) diagram:
Is it possible to make the client attached to the secondary switch that is assigned the static IP 192.168.2.3 traverse the secondary router, such that it behaves as if it was attached directly to the primary router/LAN?  I would need for the 192.168.2.2 client attached to the Main Switch to be able to ping/communicate with the 192.168.2.3 client on the secondary switch as if they were on the same switch.
Thanks,
Casey

Routers route packets between different networks. That is routing. If you want to bridge, then you use a switch to bridge different segments of the same network. Some routers, e.g. Cisco have something like IRB (integrated routing and bridging), but we do not have your router model, so we cannot answer for it.

In fact, your diagram has two different networks, so a router would route between the networks, which is the function of a router.

Technically, yes, but you NEVER EVER want to do this. (I've done this several times over the decades, because a machine has to live in the wrong network segment for one reason or other, briefly)

IRB is just routing between vlans in a switch as if you had a router that was attached  to all the vlans
